# Is every multiplicative function from the matrix ring $\text{Mat}_n(R)$ to $R$ a function of $\text{det}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$, and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\text{Mat}_n(R)$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $R$.

It is well known that the determinant function $\text{det} : \text{Mat}_n(R) \rightarrow R$ is multiplicative, i.e.

$$
\text{det}(AB) = \text{det}(A) \text{det}(B)
$$

$\text{det}$ is certainly not unique in this respect; there are lots of functions $g : \text{Mat}_n(R) \rightarrow R$ which are multiplicative. For a start, there are the constant $1$ and constant $0$ functions, as well as the indicator function of "is invertible". More strangely, for $R = \mathbb{R}$, are the functions

$$
g(A) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{f(\log(\left|\det(A)\right|))} &\text{if} \det(A) \neq 0 \\
0 &\text{if} \det(A) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

where $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any solution of the [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ : non-continuous solutions to this equation are [really badly behaved.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131197/graph-of-discontinuous-linear-function-is-dense)

However, I have not found any examples of multiplicative functions which are not themselves a function of $\det$.

**Is there any such function which is not a function of det?**

That is, is there a ring $R$, an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g : \text{Mat}_n(R) \rightarrow R$ which is multiplicative, and not a function of det, i.e. there exist $A,B \in \text{Mat}_n(R)$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
\det(A) &= \det(B) \\
g(A) &\neq g(B)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Here's one observation. If you restrict your multiplicative function to $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ you get a group map $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)\to R^\times$. If you assume further that $R$ is a field with at least three element then this follows from the fact that the derived subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ is $\mathrm{SL}_n(R)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, good point, however, I don't think the OP asks for $g(Id)$ to be $1$ so we might not get a group map... The only thing we know is that $g(Id)^2=g(Id)$ (it could be $4$ if we are working modulo $6$ for instance).

Comment: It's still fine with the assumption that $R$ is a field, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $R$ satisfies the following conditions.

- $R$ has an element $x\neq 1$ with $x^2=1$.
- There is a surjective ring homomorphism $q:R\to\mathbb{F}_2$.

For example, $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $x=-1$, or $R=S\times\mathbb{F}_2$ where $S$ has an element $s$ of multiplicative order $2$, and $x=(s,1)$.

Then $q$ induces a ring homomorphism $\text{Mat}_2(R)\to\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$,
which I'll also denote by $q$.

An element $X$ of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ acts on the three non-zero vectors of $\mathbb{F}_2^2$, and I'll say $X$ is **even** or **odd** depending on whether it acts by an even or odd permutation.

There is a multiplicative function $g:\text{Mat}_2(R)\to R$ with
$$g(A)=
\begin{cases}
0&\mbox{if $q(A)$ is not invertible}\\
1&\mbox{if $q(A)$ is invertible and even}\\
x&\mbox{if $q(A)$ is invertible and odd.} 
\end{cases}$$

But $g(A)$ is not a function of $\det(A)$, since for $A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $\det(A_1)=\det(A_2)$ but $g(A_1)=1\neq x=g(A_2)$.

Comment: Wonderful, intuitive example!

Comment: @SamCappleman-Lynes By the way, I think the example I've given is about the simplest, but it's very specific to $n=2$. There are more interesting and sophisticated examples based on calculations in algebraic $K$-theory (about which I'm far from an expert). For example, a famous example is $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$, whose "reduced Whitehead group" $SK_1(R)$ is known to be cyclic of order $2$. It turns out that this implies that for any $n>1$ there's a multiplicative function of the kind you're asking about, taking values of $0$ (for non-invertible matrices), $1$ and $-1$.