# How to interpret the functional identity $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-equations

I know that $y=kx$ is definitely a solution. Other solutions may be constructed by treating the real numbers as a vector field over the rational numbers, which are pathological.

**Question: Is there such an $f$ having its graph dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$?**

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-linear (or "pathological") solutions have graphs that are dense in the plane.  See, eg, [this SEM overview article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).  Or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131197/graph-of-discontinuous-linear-function-is-dense).