# Group homomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Let $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a group homomorphism W. R. T.  Usual addition such that $f$ is bounded at a neighborhood of $0$. Can you conclude that $f$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: Yeah you can, this is a well known exercise (You can find it in Bartle, Real Analysis, or for a solution in Conjecture and Proof by Laczkovitz)

Comment: Can you please give me any hint??

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation Basically once  such an $f$ is bounded over any interval, it must be of the form $f(x)=cx$.

Comment: [$\LaTeX{}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) help.

Comment: Also on this site you can find [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492). For example, this might be helpful: [Graph of discontinuous linear function is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131197).