# Does the condition such that $f(x+h)+f(x-h)$ has limit implies existence of left and right limit?

Tags: limits, analysis, continuity

I have a periodic function $f$ with period $1$. I want to know if this limits exists
$$ 
\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)+f(x-h)
$$
implies that both left and right limit exist?

In other words, if limit of $f(x+h) + f(x-h) $ exists as $h \to 0 $ then $f(x+) $ and $f(x-) $ (which is limit of $f(x+h) $ and $f(x-h) $ as $h \rightarrow 0$) exists.

Comment: No, you can not guarantee the existence of one-sided limits. Consider a function where the one sided limit doesn’t exist (at $x=0$, say). Try to modify the function to make the written limit exist, but by construction, the one-sided limits don’t exist.

Comment: Look at $f(y)=\begin{cases}\sin(1/y),&x\neq0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$ on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and repeat it periodically. Take $x=0$. then $\lim_{h\to0}(f(h)+f(-h))=\lim_{h\to0}(\sin(1/h)-\sin(1/h))=0$. However, $\lim_{h\to0^+}f(h)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\sin(1/h)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: In fact, we can have $f(x+h)+f(x-h) = 2f(x)$ for each $x$ and each $h,$ which clearly implies "$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x+h)+f(x-h)]$ exists for each $x$", and still have neither left nor right limit exist **anywhere**. In fact, the graph of such a function can even be dense in the plane, which is way, way worse than nonexistence at each point of a unilateral limit. See [Graph of discontinuous linear function is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131197/13130).

Comment: If you guys are going to completely answer the question, why not do it as an answer so that the question doesn't appear as though it's unanswered hours later?

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\forall x\in\Big(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\Big)\setminus\{0\}$$
$$f(0)=0$$
Extend this function over $\mathbb R$ periodically as desired. Observe that given limit is 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\Big(\frac{1}{h}+\frac{1}{-h}\Big)=0$$
but neither left nor right limit exists finitely.